# Lodash: Search a string for at least 1 value in an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a lodash function that takes an array of needles, and searches a string (haystack) for at least one match? For example:

```
let needles = ['one', 'two', 'three']
let str = 'one in every thousand will quit their jobs'
```

I need to search `str` to see if it contains at least one of the `needles`. I can implement this without lodash, but if there's a function that will help out I'd rather not reinvent the wheel as I already have lodash loaded into my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Use [***`Array#some`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), *The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.*

```js
let needles = ['one', 'two', 'three']
let str = 'one in every thousand will quit their jobs';

let bool = needles.some(function(el) {
  return str.indexOf(el) > -1;
});
console.log(bool);
```

Comment: I didn't know `Array` had a `some` method. Thank you.

Comment: @BugHunterUK – Here is the [__reference__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.protype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
needles.some(function(needle) {
    return str.includes(needle);
});
```

Or their lodash's equivalents:

```
_.some(needles, function(needle) {
    return _.includes(str, needle);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.some()` to iterate the needles, testing if it can be found in the string.

```
let found = _.some(needles, function(needle) {
    return str.indexOf(needle) != -1;
});
```

However, if there are lots of needles, it may be more efficient to convert it to a regular expression.

```
let needleRE = new RegExp(needles.map(_.escapeRegExp).join('|'));
let found = needleRE.test(str);
```

Comment: You'd want to `escapeRegExp` those needles if you're building a regex with them, though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That's not a standard JS function, so I've just put in a link to another question that shows the code for it.

Comment: Since OP mentioned lodash, I was referring to lodash's function: https://lodash.com/docs#escapeRegExp

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks, didn't know about that, updated the answer to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let needles = ['one', 'two', 'three']
let str = 'one in every thousand will quit their jobs'

let joinedNeedles = needles.join("|");
let regex = new RegExp(joinedNeedles)

let matches = str.match(regex) // ['one']
```

matches will return an array of matched ones.